# C# NAudio makes Noise WAV file without errors after POST from another page

Tags: c#, audio, wav, naudio

I am posting a file in  callback(base64data); to the server using.  When I get the file all seems well but the file sounds like white noise.  Thanks for your help.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var strUser = Request.Form["UserId"];
    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(strUser);
    var reader = new RawSourceWaveStream(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream, new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1));
    var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
    var target = new WaveFormat(44100, 8, 1);
    var lastFileName = timeStamp + "_" + strUser + ".wav";
    var saveStreamFile = @"C:\SOUNDBOX\" + lastFileName;
    var str = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, reader);
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(saveStreamFile, str);
    reader.Close();
    str.Close();
```

NOW I HAVE THIS: (please let me know the silly things that jump out at you that could make the wav sound slow motion)
But it made a WAV that plays back SLOOOOOWLY:

```
    var saveStreamFile = @"C:\SOUNDBOX\" + lastFileName;
    var wavFileStr = Convert.FromBase64String(Request["data"].Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/").Replace("\n", String.Empty).Replace("\r", String.Empty).Replace("data:audio/wav;base64,", String.Empty));
    MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(wavFileStr, 0, wavFileStr.Length);

    var target = new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1);
    var reader = new RawSourceWaveStream(stm, new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1));
    var str = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, reader);
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(saveStreamFile, str);
    reader.Close();
    str.Close();
```

Comment: don't you need to decode the base64? I don't think NAudio does this for you.

Comment: Oh, then how should I post the file?

Comment: Am I right in assuming that `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream` is base64 encoded? If so then you need to figure out a way to decode it before plumbing it through NAudio. I don't know what is available in C# for doing that though otherwise I would have written an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation for the file playing back slowly is that you've got the wrong wave format. Number of channels and sample rate being the most likely explanation.

So where you have `new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1)`, how do you know that is the correct format? I'd suggest trying with 2 channels - `new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2)`, - that will double the playback speed.

Comment: That was way too easy! I spend 3 hours on that. Thanks!